# Selenium: can't get past a login pop-up window with no source code

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, automation, popupwindow

I've tried several different methods for sending keys to the inputs, but nothing is working.

I've tried finding by xpath, ID, partial_text, etc then .send_keys(), but it can't find the pop up window.

Since the cursor autofocuses on the Username input I tried to use

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get("my_website.com")

actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.send_keys('username')
actions.perform()
```

but even then, my chrome browser isn't finding and submitting the popup window.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I was also trying a post request and methods for managing alerts.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you getting basic authentication popup where you need to enter the login credentials to log on to the website? If yes, you can resolve it by passing credentials in the url itself as below:
`browser.get("https://username:password@my_website.com")`

Comment: Can you post a link to the website...?

Comment: Hey Kireeti, your solution worked perfectly! You're the bomb! 

Alichino, sorry I can't post the link because it's a private internal site.